# Не происходит обновление ресурсов при redeploy

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, spring, java-ee

Контекст проблемы:

- Фреймворк: Spring MVC
- Цель: простое приложение
- IDE: Intellij IDEA

Когда перерисовываю текстуры в фотошопе, например задний фон и заменяю их в `/resources/images` то в какой-то момент я заметил, что при редеплое (Ctrl+F10) когда открывается `index.jsp` ресурсы не изменяются. При перезапуске сервера (Apache Tomcat) - то же самое. Удалял `target`, никакого эффекта.

Что характерно, не меняется даже styles.css. Я внёс туда некоторые изменения и в `styles.css` содержится, например:

```
.btn-5 {
    margin-left: 3%;
    /*   margin-top: 2%; HMMMM MAYBE
    margin-bottom: 2%; */

    width: 200px;
    height: 110px;
    font-family: "MyWebFont", serif;
    ...
}
```

А когда открывается index.jsp в браузере, то через Ctrl+Shift+C я вижу по-прежнему как это было до изменения:

```
.btn-5 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;

    width: 200px;
    height: 110px;
    font-family: "MyWebFont", serif;
    ...
}
```

Третий день ума не приложу, в чём тут может быть эта магия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Что нужно проверить по шагам:

1. меняется ли картинка в папке `target`?
2. на какую картинку смотрит `jsp` и/или `css`?
3. обновить кеш браузера: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
4. **проверить папку tomcat, куда он проект деплоит** - при необходимости остановить `tomcat` и принудительно удалить старую версию проекта.